# Laravel validation not showing the default error messages

Tags: validation, laravel, message

I am working on a laravel project and I am having some issues with the validation.
The default error messages dont appear instead I get to see the validation requirements like this: http://gyazo.com/681e9d8e2e176a29d90db041354f7177

this is my code:

routes.php (I put all the code in here for now)

```
Route::filter('checkLogin', function()
{


   if(Input::GET('email') != ""){ //register


        $rules =
        array(
            'username' => 'required|max:64|min:3|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|max:64|min:6',
            'fname' => 'required|max:255|alpha',
            'lname' => 'required|max:255|alpha',

            'email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'phone' => 'max:24|min:9',
            'zip' => 'required',
            'street' => 'required|max:255|alpha',
            'housenumber' => 'required|max:6|numeric',
            'country' => 'required',
            'avatar' => 'max:32'
       );


    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($rules);
    }
}
```

});

this is how the code from the view:

```
                   <div class="fields">
                        <div class="field">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            {{ Form::text('username', null, ['placeholder' => 'Username', 'tabindex' => 1]) }}
                            {{ $errors->first('username') }}

                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            {{ Form::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'tabindex' => 2]) }}
                            <a href="forgot" class="fa fa-question-circle login" title="Forgot Password?"></a>
                            {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When validation fails, you are returning your `$rules` as the errors. Change this line:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($rules);
```

to this:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```